# Windows XP command line for zipping files

Tags: windows, zip

Is there a way to zip the files in XP using the windows default zip utility through command prompt?

Comment: The zipping feature is a function of the Explorer shell and not exposed any other way.

Comment: I believe that this question should be asked on SuperUser

Answer (score 3):

You can't use this tool from the command line in Windows XP.

The best solution would be the free open source tool [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which is very good for creating zip files.  I have used this from the command line in XP, and for writing batch files, and it's very good.  A simple example:

```
7za a files.zip *.txt
```

(this adds all the text files in the current directory to an new archive called files.zip)

There is also the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en), which can be installed on XP and includes a command line `compress`, but you will not get such a good result with this (less reliable, worse compression, harder to use and less options)

---

Edit: Actually, I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875457/is-it-possible-to-unzip-zip-file-using-bat-command-on-windows-xp), which does have a (somewhat convoluted) way to do this.  But they recommend 7zip too.

Answer (score 0):

when i wanted to use zip a file thru command line in the past, i've used [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), which comes with a CLI. just add the folder to the PATH.